# JAVAFX Gluon execute View from android activity

Tags: javafx, google-cloud-messaging, gluon

Following my previous question about [messaging on javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030047/javafx-gluon-execute-controller-from-view),

I want to notify user when message arrive.
Recently I use NotificationCompat.

When user touch the notification from notification bar, it must directly open related view (DirectMessageView).
I’ve  configure an activity class (NotificationActivy extends Activity) on receive tag in androidmanifest.xml and call DirectMessageView and it's presenter on method "onCreate".

when user touch message on notification, it won’t display DirectMessageView, but the method inside presenter is called, and the view is not visible. Perhaps it’s my wrong implementation, please help

Here are classes I have created

**Class SKSAplication that extends MobileAplication**

```
public class SKSApplication extends MobileApplication{
   private static SKSApplication instance;
   public static final String DIRECT_MESSAGE_VIEW = "DIRECT_MESSAGE_VIEW";
   public static final String GROUP_MESSAGE_VIEW = "GROUP_MESSAGE_VIEW";
private ViewRefresh activeView;

   public SKSApplication() {
       instance = this;
   }

   public static SKSApplication getInstance() {
       return instance;
   }

@Override
public void init() {
   addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () -> {
        HomeView homeView = new HomeView();
        homePresenter = (HomePresenter) homeView.getPresenter();
        return (View) homeView.getView();
    });

    addViewFactory(DIRECT_MESSAGE_VIEW, () -> {
        DirectMessageView directMessageView = new DirectMessageView();
        return (View) directMessageView.getView();
    });

    addViewFactory(GROUP_MESSAGE_VIEW, () -> {
        GroupMessageView groupMessageView = new GroupMessageView();
        return (View) groupMessageView.getView();
    });

    public void doRefreshMessageUI(Object objectModel) {
    System.out.println("SKSApplication.doRefreshMessageUI " + getView().getName());
    if (getActiveView() != null)
        getActiveView().doRefresh(objectModel);
}

public ViewRefresh getActiveView() {
    return activeView;
}

public void setActiveView(ViewRefresh activeView) {
    this.activeView = activeView;
}
 }
```

**Class MyGCMListenerService**

```
public class MyGCMListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
private final String NOTIFICATION_TAG = "NotificationExample";

public MyGCMListenerService() {
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
String varMessage = data.getString("message");
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(varMessage);

        String messageContent = getStringFromJSON(json, "message");
        Integer senderId = getIntegerFromJSON(json, "senderId");
        String senderName = getStringFromJSON(json, "senderName");
        String comId = getStringFromJSON(json, "communityId");
        String salesGroup = getStringFromJSON(json, "salesGroup");
        Integer messageType = getIntegerFromJSON(json, "type");

        doViewNotification(messageType, senderName, salesGroup);
     SKSApplication.getInstance().doRefreshMessageUI(messageContent,senderId,senderName,comId );
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void doViewNotification(Integer messageType, String senderName, String salesGroup) {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder()
            .append("Message from ")
            .append(senderName)
            .append(" @").append(salesGroup);


    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(FXActivity.getInstance(), NotificationActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_INTENT.MESSAGE_TYPE.getValue(), messageType);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    FXActivity.getInstance(),
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    long[] v = {500, 1000};


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSound(uri)
                    .setSmallIcon(FXActivity.getInstance().getApplicationInfo().icon)
                    .setContentTitle(getApplicationName(FXActivity.getInstance().getApplicationContext()))
                    .setVibrate(v)
                    .setContentText(msg.toString())
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setNumber(100)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .addAction(FXActivity.getInstance().getApplicationInfo().icon, "Action", null);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, 0, builder.build());
    } else {
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG.hashCode(), builder.build());
    }

}
}
```

**layout xml file (directmessage.fxml)**

```
<View xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="directMessageView" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="400.0"
  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40"
  fx:controller="com.tenma.mobile.message.directmessage.DirectMessagePresenter">
</View>
```

**Class DirectMessageView**

```
public class DirectMessageView extends FXMLView {
}
```

**Class DirectMessagePresenter**

```
public class DirectMessagePresenter implements Initializable, ViewRefresh{
    @Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    {
        directMessageView.showingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            SKSApplication.getInstance().setActiveView(this);
            doViewMessage();
        }
   });
    }

    private void doViewMessage() {
    listMessage.getItems().clear();

    MessageStoryHelper hlp = new MessageStoryHelper();
    List<MessageModel> ls = null;
    try {
        ls = hlp.getMessages(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE.DIRECT);
    if (ls != null && ls.size() != 0)
        for (MessageModel m :ls)
            listMessage.add(m);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

**androidmanifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.tenma.mobile"
      android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<permission android:name="com.tenma.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.tenma.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application android:label="MobileSales" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="MobileSales"
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.tenma.mobile.SKSApplication"/>
        <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name="com.tenma.mobile.common.NotificationActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="javafxports.android.FXActivity">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="javafxports.android.FXActivity"/>
    </activity>

    <!--start-->
    <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <!-- for Gingerbread GSF backward compat -->
            <!--<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>-->
            <category android:name="com.tenma.mobile"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--end-->

    <service
            android:name="com.tenma.mobile.common.MyGCMListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
    </manifest>
```

**Class NotificationActivity extends Activity**

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent launchIntent = getIntent();
```

it working, but no view is visible

```
SKSApplication.getInstance().switchView(SKSApplication.DIRECT_MESSAGE_VIEW);
```

perhaps using this line below, but how to set Gluon View setContentView?
or retreive view ID and setContentView?

```
DirectMessageView directMessageView = new DirectMessageView();
                Parent v = directMessageView.getView();
                FXActivity.getInstance().setContentView(?????????);
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987787/open-activity-when-gcm-notification-was-clicked

Comment: Thank you, I need to call Gluon View Inside Android Activity after NotificationActivity is initialized. On android activity there is a setContentView. but I don't know yet how to make Gluon View enable to set into android setContentView. Perhap I miss some implementation

Comment: I found you can setContentView like this: 'FXActivity.getInstance().setContentView(R.layout.defaultlayout);'  I copied a layout file from an android eclipse project to my javafxports eclipse project into res/layout folder in my project folders

Comment: You need a  'import com.example.R;' to match your package so that 'R.layout.defaultlayout' can be resolved. And your class needs to 'extends Activity'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the application running, this works for me:

Once you send the message back to the View, you need to close the notification activity by calling `finish()`:

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((SKSApplication) MobileApplication.getInstance()).doRefreshMessageUI("Hi from NotificationActivity");

        finish();
    }

}
```

Note you don't need to create a singleton instance of `SKSApplication`, you can retrieve an instance of it at any time by calling `MobileApplication.getInstance()`.

Passing the message to the view can be done in `SKSApplication` by using `Platform.runLater()`, since you are not running on the JavaFX thread.

And to retrieve the corresponding view, just switch to that view:

```
public void doRefreshMessageUI(String msg) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        messagesView.messageProperty().set(msg);
        switchView(DIRECT_MESSAGE_VIEW);
    });
}
```

providing the view has a `StringProperty`, that is bound to any of its controls text property.

```
private StringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty();

public StringProperty messageProperty() {
    return message;
}
```